# Loading empty form

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a page with 3 containers, the top will be used for search form, two the left side will have the adf form and the right a table view. One thing to note is that all the 3 sections will be using the same View Object or inturn the same table. When the page is loaded I want my form to come in the createInsert view. I tried using the invoke criteria for the creatInsertaction but this is messing up my search, since the form is empty and if i do a search in the search form the validators in the ADF form will fire and every thing goes for a toes.

Please suggest any solutions for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use different view instances. Probably 1 for the search and 1 for both the form and the table.
Some basic info about view instances: http://andrejusb.blogspot.be/2011/06/understanding-adf-bc-view-object.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same viewObject but add some viewCriteria for the search part, and use a CreateInsert in your taskflow before show the view.

Answer (score 0):

use mange-Bean and do create insert pragmatically inside the constructor .